# Как получить русский текст из utf-8?

Tags: php, unicode

**UPDATE 19.11.2022**
Я решил проблему, но т.к. она была давно а обновить вопрос я решил только сейчас, я уже забыл конкретное решение. Однако я помню, что дело было в локализации linux на которой висел сервер или типа того. Надеюсь эта подсказка направит кого-то в правильном направлении.

Скорее всего я пропускаю что-то очевидное, пробовал разные варианты декодирования. Суть в том, что есть php код, который выводит результат выполнения python скрипта, который возвращает русский текст в utf-8, вот код:

PHP:
[![PHP][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddbfW.jpg
Код питон скрипта(generate() возвращает текст):

```
`print(generate(sys.argv[1]).encode("utf-8"))`
```

Вывод: b'\xd0\x9e\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8f, \xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb1\xd1\x8b \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe.' ? ???????

Comment: Напишите какой текст должен выдавать python, напишите какой текст выводит php без декодирования и прочей ерунды

Comment: В данном случае должен выводить:"Однако обидно будет потратить на дела время, которое могли бы провести более плодотворно", вывод без декодирования выглядит так же, как и после применения utf8_decode()

Comment: Для начала надо понять, что все эти палочки - это НЕ utf-8.

Comment: ну черт, я в онлайн-декодерах проверял, там то как URL Encoding определяет, то как utf-8, а в итоге правильно декодируется

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать функцию mb_convert_encoding. Пример для вашего текста:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d2363884f75f44989e6931efd188e7e0a31d154

или unpack

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44568f0d9cadbcd759505bc62cff4f4daae3e920

Comment: проблема в том, что такая конвертация не работает именно при использовании shell_execute(), при этом strval() и settype() не помогают, как будто это перестаёт считаться строкой

Comment: а unpack() только в сэндбоксе возвращает русский, на странице отображается неизменённый текст